# R sorting a list

Tags: r, sorting

I have a group of data that looks like this (earningsCont):

```
          Total
AUD   -19556.74
BRL        0.00
CAD  -163998.27
CHF   -32616.65
CNY   -45431.39
EUR -1011586.67
GBP -1656961.94
HKD   -10447.83
JPY  -297209.34
PLN   -41066.64
MXN   -24674.11
NZD  -154168.05
```

when I enter this command, I lose the row names:

```
earningsCont[order(earningsCont$Total),]
```

that command gives me this:

```
 [1] -1656961.94 -1011586.67  -297209.34  -163998.27  -154168.05   -45431.39   -41066.64   -32616.65
 [9]   -24674.11   -19556.74   -10447.83        0.00
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.  I juat want the same list I started with but ordered by the 'Total' column.

Comment: `earningsCont[order(earningsCont$Total), , drop=FALSE]` you need `drop` for one column if you want the result to remain a matrix/data.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for a single column return from `[.data.drame` is to loose the 'data.frame' class and just give a vector. You can prevent this with a third argument `drop=FALSE` (I called mine `dat`)

```
> dat[order(dat$Total), , drop=FALSE]
          Total
GBP -1656961.94
EUR -1011586.67
JPY  -297209.34
CAD  -163998.27
NZD  -154168.05
CNY   -45431.39
PLN   -41066.64
CHF   -32616.65
MXN   -24674.11
AUD   -19556.74
HKD   -10447.83
BRL        0.00
```

If you did want the sorted values with the associated rownames this would deliver:

```
> setNames( dat[order(dat$Total),], rownames(dat)[order(dat$Total)] )
        GBP         EUR         JPY         CAD         NZD         CNY 
-1656961.94 -1011586.67  -297209.34  -163998.27  -154168.05   -45431.39 
        PLN         CHF         MXN         AUD         HKD         BRL 
  -41066.64   -32616.65   -24674.11   -19556.74   -10447.83        0.00
```

Comment: In your second suggestion, the data is sorted but the names are not, so the labels are associated with the wrong data.